connection Ttl = -1 not working for STOMP connections in ActiveMQ Artemis
Even though I've set the connection TTL to -1 at the STOMP protocol level and configured <connection-ttl-override> to -1 within the  section of the broker.xml file, I'm still encountering an error indicating a timeout issue:
Received error: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:63509 within the 60000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.

My requirement is that the server should never timeout the connection.

Why is your requirement that the server should never timeout a STOMP connection? The broker cleans up abandoned or dead connections so that it can continue operating normally. If it doesn't clean up such connections then eventually it will run out of resources and cease functioning properly.

The broker doesn't allow a connection TTL of -1 for STOMP connections. Such a setting would mean that the broker would never clean up abandoned or dead connections. However, if it doesn't clean up such connections then eventually it will run out of resources and cease functioning properly.
If fact, if you attempt to set connectionTtl=-1 on the acceptor URL you should receive an error that says something like this:
Stomp Connection TTL cannot be negative

I recommend you use STOMP heart-beating to keep your connection from being closed in the absence of any messages flowing.
